# CastleWindsor Register all Classes With default interface in Silverlight

Tags: vb.net, c#-4.0, silverlight-4.0, castle-windsor

I need to scan my assembly and register all classes that have a default interface with Castle.
For example: `MySpecialClass` should be registered if `IMySpecialClass` exists.

vb.net registry:

```
Public Class UiRegistry
    Implements IWindsorInstaller

    Public Sub Install(ByVal container As IWindsorContainer, ByVal store As IConfigurationStore) Implements IWindsorInstaller.Install
        container.Register(Classes.FromThisAssembly().)
    End Sub
End Class
```

This is where i got but i can't find any implementation that provide what i require.

Answer (score 2):

It was quiet simple:

```
 container.Register(Classes.FromThisAssembly().Pick().WithServiceDefaultInterfaces())
```

I just needed to use the .Pick() to select the Classes and then i could select the option to configure there interfaces.